# How to I use angular material autocomplete with complex objects?

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete, ngrx

I am building an application that uses Angular Material in Angular 16.  I have ngrx state management gathering an array of objects to pick from. I want the input to display the name property of this object when one is picked from the autocomplete options. I am currently using a matInput with mat-autocomplete.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AsyncPipe} from '@angular/common';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { TokenNameWithId } from '../../../shared/models/card.model';
import { Observable, combineLatest, debounceTime, map, startWith } from 'rxjs';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectAllTokenNames } from '../+state/token-names.selectors';

@Component({
  selector: 'tokenator-tokens-dropdown',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AsyncPipe
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  templateUrl: './tokens-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrl: './tokens-dropdown.component.scss',
})
export class TokensDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  public tokenNamesControl = new FormControl<string>('', {
    nonNullable: true,
  });
  public filteredTokenNames!: Observable<TokenNameWithId[]>;
  private tokenNames$ = this.store.select(selectAllTokenNames);

  constructor(private store: Store) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredTokenNames = combineLatest([
      this.tokenNamesControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
      this.tokenNames$,
    ]).pipe(
      debounceTime(250),
      map(([value, tokenNamesWithId]) => value ? this._filter(value, tokenNamesWithId) : tokenNamesWithId
    ));
  }

  private _filter(value: string, tokenNamesWithId: TokenNameWithId[]): TokenNameWithId[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return tokenNamesWithId.filter((tokenNameWithId: TokenNameWithId) => tokenNameWithId.displayName.includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

```css
.example-form {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .example-full-width {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Token</mat-label>
        <input 
            type="text"
            placeholder="Select a token"
            aria-label="Token name"
            matInput
            [formControl]="tokenNamesControl"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            @for (tokenName of filteredTokenNames | async ; track tokenName) {
                <mat-option [value]="tokenName">{{tokenName.displayName}}</mat-option>
            }
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

This results in odd behavior from the matInput where the search in autocomplete works, I can select a object, but the displayed value is `[object Object]`.  This makes sense, since the underlying selected value from the autocomplete is an object, but I would like the input to have a displayed text of `tokenName.displayName` just like my `<mat-options>` do.

[image: This is a display of the form input as displayed on the web page after selecting an available option from autocomplete. The list of autocomplete options displays the proper text but the input selected value is "object Object".]

Is there a way to get the `matInput` to display a property of an object selected from autocomplete? Alternatively, is there a better pairing of angular material components I should be using when selecting from an array more complex objects that preserves having working autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `[displayWith]` property to customize the displayed text for the selected option.

```
displayFn(tokenName: any): string {
  return tokenName && tokenName.displayName ? tokenName.displayName : '';
}
```

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    ...
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Reference: [Setting separate control and display values](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values)

For your reported issue:

1. Change the `FormControl<string>` to `FormControl<string | TokenNameWithId>` type.
2. Modify the `_filter` function to check the `value` type.

```
public tokenNamesControl = new FormControl<string | TokenNameWithId>('', {
    nonNullable: true,
  });

private _filter(value: string | TokenNameWithId, tokenNamesWithId: TokenNameWithId[]): any[] {
  const filterValue =
    typeof value === 'string'
      ? value.toLowerCase()
      : value.displayName.toLowerCase();

  return tokenNamesWithId.filter((tokenNameWithId: any) =>
    tokenNameWithId.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
  );
}
```

Comment: While this does solve the display issue, this breaks the autocomplete after selection.  Once a `TokenNameWithId` is selected and placed in the input the filter receives the object instead of a string causing an error: `TypeError: value.toLowerCase is not a function` since the object in the input is no longer a string.

Comment: The filter can be fixed by separating out strings from objects and making the type of the value input `unknown`.

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer. For similar [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/edk1vu?file=src%2Fexample%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts).